# htaccess tweaking required

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I have this htaccess which works great. I would like to do one more thing. I have the urls in the site tightly controlled it works fine. I would like to prevent people from adding arbitrary requests to the site.

I am using friendly urls. My urls work like this:

```
http://www.mysite.net/pagename
```

So if you try to put in a non existent page you get a 404 error. This all works fine. But I would like to restrict things further.

Currently if you put in index.php it works too and you get brought to

```
http://www.mysite.net/index.php
```

I want to restrict this behaviour as people can add and search engines can index add arbitrary requests to the url like

```
http://www.mysite.net/index.php?test=somthing
```

and this does not throw a 404 but goes to the home page index.php. I would like these types of urls to throw 404's.

My htaccess is below is there anything I can do to fix it there.

```
RewriteEngine On


#RewriteRule ^gallery(/((([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/(\d+))?)/?)?)?$ index.php?page=77&groupId=$4&showpage=$6 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^gallery/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?page=77&groupId=$1&showpage=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=77&groupId=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/?$ index.php?page=77 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^video/(\d+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=60&showpage=$1&v=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^video/(\d+)/?$ index.php?page=60&showpage=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^video/?$ index.php?page=60 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```